# How can I delete image from rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-admin

I am using the [rails_admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin).

I was wondering how can I delete the gravatar image in the top right corner?

And How can I change other view elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be achieved by coping [_secondary_navigation.html.haml](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml) to your app's **app/view/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml** and editing in the way you want.
Isn't it enough?

```
%ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.root_links
  - actions(:root).each do |action|
    %li{class: "#{action.action_name}_root_link"}= link_to wording_for(:menu, action), { action: action.action_name, controller: 'rails_admin/main' }, class: "pjax"
  - if main_app_root_path = (main_app.root_path rescue false)
    %li= link_to t('admin.home.name'), main_app_root_path
  - if _current_user
    - if user_link = edit_user_link
      %li= user_link
    - if logout_path.present?
      %li= link_to content_tag('span', t('admin.misc.log_out'), class: 'label label-danger'), logout_path, method: logout_method
    - if _current_user.respond_to?(:email) && _current_user.email.present?
      %li= image_tag "#{(request.ssl? ? 'https://secure' : 'http://www')}.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest _current_user.email}?s=30", style: 'padding-top:5px'
```

the key is `%li= image_tag "#{(request.ssl? ? 'https://secure' : 'http://www')}.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest _current_user.email}?s=30", style: 'padding-top:5px'`

Comment: no problem I always like to help when I can. I am personally not a big fan of gravatars as no one that is not a developer has one. :).